# Internal links to 1 page from 200 internal blog posts

Tags: seo, link-building

I am running website that has a product that is described in around 200 different blog posts. All of them very much make sence, its unique and quite informative for users. Users are landing on those blog posts quite often from google search, so SEO is working good for them.

One page of website is large complex booking form that covers all types of differentiations of this product described in blogs.

For better user experience (if they want to make a booking), and to possibly increase my sales, I would on bottom of each blog add link "book now" directing  to the page that has booking form.
Would this be good or bad for SEO ?

Comment: Can you provide an example link?

Comment: Doesn't sound natural and I think the Googlebot will agree... natural links vary in anchors, vary in platforms and so on. Bottomline, user generated links is not something you want to many of.

Comment: I think so too, i could make several anchors natural but not 200 of them. Part of the booking form could be on each blog post, but i am not sure is that worse then making 200 links.